# Mouse Move event issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have developed Mac Style Doc Menu. The doc menu will show when the cursor is 100px from the bottom. Else the menu is hidden. Now the problem is i can take e.clientX and e.clientY only when the cursor is stationary.

Is there any way to solve this? Below is the code that i have used for animation.

```
$(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    if ((window.innerHeight - e.clientY) <= 50) {
        $('.wrap').stop(true);
        $('.wrap').animate({
            bottom: 5
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $('.wrap').stop(true);
        $('.wrap').animate({
            bottom: -100
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI, `$(window).mousemove()` generally cause big performance issue, you should find an other logic without using it

Comment: I thinks you have to creat invisible <div class="bottom-block"> for exemple in the bottom with 50px height and use $('.bottom-block').mouseover to make turn animation while mouse is in the block

Comment: @A. Wolff  i could not find any other way to do it. $('.bottom-block').mouseover is a solution but i wouldn't get the same doc menu style i wanted

Comment: @MacleanPinto just set a console.log() inside this handler and now check your console. This cannot be a viable solution in any case. I'm sure using other logic is possible but to get better help, you should provide a working example as a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your Suggestions.

After spending hours on this issue just thought i should share the solution is found. Instead of using Jquery, i used plane JavaScript event listener and added call back function when the condition matched.

Simple example of how to add a event lister. If any one needs the entire code please let me know i will add that too.

```
var myListener = function (e) {

    document.body.innerHTML = 'Mouse first moved: ' + e.clientY +"---"+e.clientX
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', myListener, false);
```

Link to the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JQBmA/#&togetherjs=wUsP1yGylU

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To ease with the performance, you can delay the event a bit, e.g.:

```
var moveTimer = null;
$(window).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(moveTimer);
    moveTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        // only runs when the user stops moving the mouse for 10ms
    }, 10);
});
```

See: **[A simple prototype of the dock (JSFIDDLE)](http://jsfiddle.net/9yXsg/3/)**